# Range from -1, 1 to 0, 1

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a problem. I have a set of values ranging from -1 to 1.

I want a function or an equation that would map all the values from -1, 1 to 0, 1.

Means, if the original value is -1, then the computed value should be 0. If the original value is 0, then the computed value should be .5. If the original value is 1, then the computed value should stay as 1.

I am new to all this, so I dont even know if I am asking the question in correct form.

Comment: $y= \frac{1}{2}(x+1)$.

Comment: $y=\dfrac 12+\dfrac {x}{\sqrt{1+3x^2}}$ and more generally, any sigmoid based function would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this in stages.  First I would ask myself how would I map $-1$ to $0$?

Well I would add $1$ to the value.  So our map would be $f(x) = x + 1$ and now we have a function that maps $(-1, 1)$ to $(0,2)$.  The next step would be how would I map $2$ back to $1$ without changing the zero value.  Halving it gives us that so we can make a function $f(x) = \frac{x + 1}{2}$.

In general when you are dealing with a math problem if you can figure out how to separate into multiple simpler problems then solve them.